# Android developer/publisher royalty sharing

Tags: android, publishing, revenue

I am creating and Android game, and will need to partner with a publisher. I am curious about how this is typically implemented. Probably publishers are going to have a difficult time trusting some developer that they don't know to pay them, assuming the develop puts the game up on Google Play. So will the publisher want the apk file so that they can put it up on Google Play themselves?

Or does Google Play have a mechanism where the royalties can be automatically split between two parties from sales/IAP?

I know that all contracts will be different and it will depend, but I'm just looking to get a general idea of what is usual/typical.

Comment: Awesome Philipp. I wanted to use "royalties" also but it wouldn't let me do that either.

Comment: Assuming there's a legal contract between the two parties, does it really matter who uploads the apk? Google Play has a way to allow separate users to manage apps, I'm not sure if it supports permissions, but wouldn't be surprised if it did.

Comment: @ Tom Tsagk It matters because only one party owns the account and sets up banking info for Google to send the money. You won't have multiple users from different organizations (dev and publisher) having access to someone's personal bank account.